# Do we really know the value of expressions with irrational powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

The way we evaluate decimal powers such as $a^.75$ is by splitting it into $(a^3)$^(1/4). How then can we evaluate irrational powers? I know that we can approximate, but whenever we graph a^x we assume continuity at the irrational numbers, but how can we be certain of this?

Comment: Excellent question. Essentially, it's done just like you suggest, simply by approximating. Since the irrationals are dense in the reals (so for every irrational number there is a rational number as close as we like), we use better and better *rational* approximations, and define the irrational power as the limit of these approximations.

Comment: More advanced definition: first study functions $\log$ and $\exp$, then define $a^b = \exp(b \log a)$ for $a>0$.

Comment: Oh ok thanks guys I understand. So we $define$ irrational powers so that our function $a^x$ is continuous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *definition* is that $a^b = e^{b \ln a}$ for positive $a$. This agrees on the rational points with what you get by roots and powers, and is continuous in $b$, so it is a decent definition.

Comment: How do you conclude that it is continuous in b?

Comment: We can prove that $e^x, \ln,$ and multiplication are continuous, and that compositions of continuous functions are continuous.